# Valgrind possibly lost memory in simple programs

Tags: c, valgrind

Whatever program I run Valgrind tells me that there are 72 possibly lost bytes in 3 blocks, even with a simple program like:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Do you know if this is a Valgrind bug on Mac OS sierra?

How could I leak memory with a program like this?

Comment: It says 'possibly lost'.  Probably somethng in the crt.  If it's always there, and doesn't grow, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can very likely happen, if any of the preloaded libraries (e.g. via `LD_PRELOAD`), or any parts of the linked C runtime have memory leaks.

There are also a couple of memory allocations performed by the CRT which are never freed on purpose, but typically these are only a one-time thing and only happen once per process.

Valgrind can not reliably distinguish between what's part of your application at what isn't. You can only check the stack trace from where the memory was allocated, and decide whether that is your domain or not.

Comment: And you can generate suppressions for such errors because they don't belong to your program. In fact, *valgrind* comes with many suppressions for known issues.

Comment: Note that memory allocated and not released, but to which a reference still remains, is not a leak.  It's not uncommon, or even necessarily bad, to leave 'one time only' allocations to be swept up by the OS vacuum-cleaner upon process termination.